# Setting a delimiter to generate an export

Tags: vba, excel

I found a VBA code that almost fits my requirements to export data to a CSV file. I am having problems with the delimiter function.

I have the following function:

```
Function DelimitRange(ByVal XLArray As Variant) As String
 Const delimiter As String = ","
 Const lineFeed As String = vbCrLf
 Const removeExisitingDelimiter As Boolean = True     
 Dim rowCount As Long
 Dim colCount As Long
 Dim tempString As String


For rowCount = LBound(XLArray, 1) To UBound(XLArray, 1)
    For colCount = LBound(XLArray, 2) To UBound(XLArray, 2)

        If removeExisitingDelimiter Then
            tempString = tempString & Replace(XLArray(rowCount, colCount), delimiter, vbNullString)
        Else
            tempString = tempString & XLArray(rowCount, colCount)
        End If

        'Don't add delimiter to column end
        If colCount < UBound(XLArray, 2) Then tempString = tempString & delimiter

    Next colCount

    'Add linefeed
    If rowCount < UBound(XLArray, 1) Then tempString = tempString & lineFeed

Next rowCount

DelimitRange = tempString

End Function
```

This code is generating me something like that:

```
a,,,
d,,z,
uo,,,
u,,c,
h,,,
```

I need this function to generate the line skipping extra commas when there is no more characters to display at the end of each line.

I need this function to give me the following output (using the same data as the example given before:

```
a
d,,z
uo
u,,c
h
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `rngArray = Excel.Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A3:D" & lineSize).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the usage of `currentItem` in the code. Modify your code according to the code below.

```
dim currentItem as string

dim lastNonBlankIndex as Integer
dim dataForTheRow 
dim stringifiedRow as string

For rowCount = LBound(XLArray, 1) To UBound(XLArray, 1)
    redim dataForTheRow(LBound(XLArray, 2) To UBound(XLArray, 2))
    lastNonBlankIndex = LBound(XLArray, 2)
    For colCount = LBound(XLArray, 2) To UBound(XLArray, 2)

        If removeExisitingDelimiter Then
            currentItem = Replace(XLArray(rowCount, colCount), delimiter, vbNullString)
        Else
            currentItem = XLArray(rowCount, colCount)
        End If
        dataForTheRow(colCount) = currentItem

        If Trim(currentItem) <> "" Then
            lastNonBlankIndex = colCount
        End If

    Next colCount

    redim preserve dataForTheRow(LBound(XLArray, 2) To lastNonBlankIndex)
    stringifiedRow = Join(dataForTheRow, delimiter)

    Debug.Print stringifiedRow

    'Add linefeed
    tempString = tempString & stringifiedRow
    If rowCount < UBound(XLArray, 1) Then
        tempString = tempString & lineFeed
    End If

Next rowCount
```

Comment: Same result as before.. I got your idea.. but its important to notice that: I need the delimiter if I have any other cell of that row with any value.. I just wont use the delimiter if that cell is the last of of that row without any value.

Comment: Does that mean the 1st row from your argument range contains "A" in the 1st column and the other 3 columns are blank, on the same row? Please check if the modified code helps.

Comment: Yeah ! Suppous that I have 10 columns and I'm going to export it to CSV. My code is exporting it properly except for the delimiter part. Suppous that I have one line with the first and the third cell populated. My output needs to be `value1,,value3` .. Suppous that the line contains the first and the eighth cell populated, the output should be: `value1,,,,,,,value8`. Now let's say that I have only the fist value, the output will be: `value1` only. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Dan-SP: Check the modified answer. I have tested it & found it to be working, as you expect it to.

Comment: Working Perfectly, man ! Thanks for your help. Just removed the debug.print instruction.. hehe..

Comment: @Dan-SP: I am glad it worked. Yes `debug.print` was for testing purpose. Also, I would advise you to break things such as stringForRow and finalOutput - for you to see things in small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the delimiters in `delimitList` and concatenate them only if some other element appears in the same row.

Please see the full code below:

```
Function DelimitRange(ByVal XLArray As Variant) As String
    Const delimiter As String = ","
    Const lineFeed As String = vbCrLf
    Const removeExisitingDelimiter As Boolean = True
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Long
    Dim tempString As String

    Dim delimitList As String
    Dim currentItem As String
    Dim tempSubString As String

    For rowCount = LBound(XLArray, 1) To UBound(XLArray, 1)
        delimitList = ""
        For colCount = LBound(XLArray, 2) To UBound(XLArray, 2)
            currentItem = XLArray(rowCount, colCount)
            If Trim(currentItem) <> "" Then
                If tempSubString <> "" Then tempSubString = tempSubString & delimiter
                tempSubString = tempSubString & delimitList
                If removeExisitingDelimiter Then
                    tempSubString = tempSubString & Replace(currentItem, delimiter, vbNullString)
                Else
                    tempSubString = tempSubString & currentItem
                End If
                delimitList = ""
            Else
                delimitList = delimitList & delimiter
            End If
        Next colCount

        tempString = tempString & tempSubString
        tempSubString = ""

        'Add linefeed
        If rowCount < UBound(XLArray, 1) Then tempString = tempString & lineFeed
    Next rowCount

    DelimitRange = tempString

End Function
```

Comment: Almost there.. I will separate the linebreaks with "/" to show the output for your code, using input the example I gave: `a/d,z/uo/u,c/h`.. The desired output is: `a/d,,z/uo/u,,c/h`. When I have any value on any cell of the row, I need to mantain the delimiter with blank `,,`.. I just need to omit it when there isn't any other value at the row.

Answer (score 0):

Line feed change:

```
'Add linefeed
If rowCount < UBound(XLArray, 1) Then 
     While tempString Like "*" & delimiter
          tempString=left(tempString, Len(tempstring)-len(delimiter))
     Wend
     tempString = tempString & lineFeed
End if
```